# Differentiate between GET and POST method in Laravel Controller

Tags: php, laravel, routes, controllers

I have 2 routes like below,

```
Route::get('/','MainController@Date');
Route::post('/','MainController@Date');
```

or

```
Route::any('/','MainController@Date');
```

When get request is called i will calculate dates and hen post request is called i will get dates from form inputs.

when post method is called in my controler

```
$date1 = $request->get ( 'date1' );
$date2 = $request->get ( 'date2' );
```

when get is called

```
$date1 = will calculate using date function
$date2 = will calculate using date function
```

How differentiate both methods get and post, if get i should one set of things and for post another set of things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class SmeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Do somthing
     * @param  Request  $request
     */
    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
    //
        }
        if ($request->isMethod('get')) {
    //
        }
    }
}
```

you could also use `$method = $request->method();`

Answer (score 4):

You can simply do this using below code

```
public function someMethod(Request $request)
{
        $method = $request->method();

        // to check if its a post method
        if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
            //
        }

        // to check if its a get method
        if ($request->isMethod('get')) {
            //
        }
}
```

The method `method()` will return the HTTP verb for the request. You may also use the isMethod method to verify that the HTTP verb matches a given string:

Comment: got similar answer from @B.Kevin , he answered fast. So i accepted it as an answer

Comment: @Mann no issues :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$request->query();//return only GET param
$request->request->all()// POST param
$request->input();//all
```